# Java compare two csv files

Tags: java, csv, dictionary, treemap

So I have two csv files i wish to compare.
Each file could be as much as 20mb each.
Each line has the key followed by the data so key,data
But the data is then separated by comma as well.

**csv1.csv**

```
KEY ,   DATA    

AB45,12,15,65,NN
AB46,12,15,64,YY
AB47,45,85,95,YN
```

**csv2.csv**

```
AB45,12,15,65,NN
AB46,15,15,65,YY
AB48,65,45,60,YY
```

What i want to do is read both files and compare the data for each key.

I was thinking read each file line by line adding into a TreeMap. I can then compare each set of data for a given key and if there is a difference write it to another file.

Any advice?
As I am unsure of how to read the files to extract just the keys and data in an efficient way.

Comment: My guess would be that doing this in your shell via unix commands might be easier than in java.  IE diff <file1> <file2>

Comment: For something this small, Java might be overkill. Also it's not clear exactly how you want to make the comparison. Does order matter or only having same keys with same values?

Comment: Do you want to implement a comparison like `diff` at linux, are your keys always sorted, do you need to load both files at memory?

Comment: The comparison ideally would be a side by side view of the lines with different data, as well as a section that outputs new keys in file 2 that aren't in file 1. Also another section to show deleted keys that are in file 1 and aren't in file 2.

Comment: The keys should always be sorted and there shouldn't be duplicates but it would be great if I could do it to unsorted files and find duplicates. Also it is not necessary to load to memory I just couldn't think of a better way than using a bufferedreader or scanner to do it.

Comment: what do keys look like in the latter of the files? Like when you get to the possible 20mb size, what do those keys/lines look like? Also is the data followed by the keys always in the format: nn,nn,nn,cc - where n=number and c=char? or do those vary and could be 1 or 2 or 3 etc. numbers/chars in length?

Comment: @DiggidyDale you should edit your question to add these things and whatever else you can think of. It's hard to answer this if you people who want to help you have to extract requirements out of you bit by bit. Think about them for a bit and then write them in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use a CSV parsing library dedicated for that to speed things up. With [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) you can parse these 20mb files in 100ms or less. The following solution is a bit involved to prevent loading too much data into memory. Check the tutorial I linked above, there are many ways to accomplish what you need with this library.

#### First we read one of the CSV files, and generate a Map:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    //First we parse one file (ideally the smaller one)
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //here we tell the parser to read the CSV headers
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    //Parse all data into a list.
    List<String[]> records = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/csv1.csv"));
    //Convert that list into a map. The first column of this input will produce the keys.
    Map<String, String[]> mapOfRecords = toMap(records);

    //this where the magic happens.
    processFile(new File("/path/to/csv2.csv"), new File("/path/to/diff.csv"), mapOfRecords);

}
```

#### This is the code to generate a Map from the list of records:

```
    /* Converts a list of records to a map. Uses element at index 0 as the key */
private static Map<String, String[]> toMap(List<String[]> records) {
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    for (String[] row : records) {
        //column 0 will always have an ID.
        map.put(row[0], row);
    }
    return map;
}
```

#### With the map of records, we can process your second file and generate another with any updates found:

```
private static void processFile(final File input, final File output, final Map<String, String[]> mapOfExistingRecords) {
    //configures a new parser again
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    //All parsed rows will be submitted to the following Processor. This way you won't have to store all rows in memory.
    settings.setProcessor(new RowProcessor() {
        //will write the changed rows to another file
        CsvWriter writer;

        @Override
        public void processStarted(ParsingContext context) {
            CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //configure at till
            writer = new CsvWriter(output, settings);
        }

        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            // Incoming rows from will have the ID as index 0.
            // If the map contains the ID, we'll get a row
            String[] existingRow = mapOfExistingRecords.get(row[0]);

            if (!Arrays.equals(row, existingRow)) {
                writer.writeRow(row);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void processEnded(ParsingContext context) {
            writer.close();
        }
    });

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    //the parse() method will submit all rows to the RowProcessor defined above. All differences will be
    //written to the output file.
    parser.parse(input);
}
```

This should work just fine. I hope it helps you.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 0):

I work with a lot of CSV file comparisons for my job. I didn't know python before I started working, but I picked it up really quick. If you want to compare CSV files quickly, python is a wonderful way to go, and its fairly easy to pick up if you know java.

I modified a script I use to fit your basic use case (you'll need to modify it a bit more to do exactly what you want). It Runs under a few seconds when I use it compare csv files with millions of rows. If you need to do this in java, you can pretty much transfer this to some java methods. There are similar csv libraries you can use that will replace all the csv functions below.

```
import csv, sys, itertools

def getKeyPosition(header_row, key_value):
    counter = 0
    for header in header_row:
        if (header == key_value):
            return counter
        counter += 1 

# This will create a dictonary of your rows by their key. (key is the column location)
def getKeyDict(csv_reader, key_position):
    key_dict = {}

    row_counter = 0
    unique_records = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        row_counter += 1
        if row[key_position] not in key_dict:
            key_dict.update({row[key_position]: row})
            unique_records += 1

    # My use case requires a lot of checking for duplicates 
    if unique_records != row_counter:
        print "Duplicate Keys in File"

    return key_dict

def main():
    f1 = open(sys.argv[1]) 
    f2 = open(sys.argv[2])
    f1_csv = csv.reader(f1)
    f2_csv = csv.reader(f2)

    f1_header = next(f1_csv)
    f2_header = next(f2_csv)
    f1_header_key_position = getKeyPosition(f1_header, "KEY")
    f2_header_key_position = getKeyPosition(f2_header, "KEY")

    f1_row_dict = getKeyDict(f1_csv, f1_header_key_position)
    f2_row_dict = getKeyDict(f2_csv, f2_header_key_position)

    outputFile = open("KeyDifferenceFile.csv" , 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
    writer.writerow(f1_header)


    #Heres the logic for comparing rows
    for key, row_1 in f1_row_dict.iteritems():
        #Do whatever comparisions you need here. 
        if key not in f2_row_dict:
            print "Oh no, this key doesn't exist in the file 2"

        if key in f2_row_dict:
            row_2 = f2_row_dict.get(key)

            if row_1 != row_2:
                print "oh no, the two rows don't match!"

            # You can get more header keys to compare by if you want.
            data_position = getKeyPosition(f2_header, "DATA")
            row_1_data = row_1[data_position]
            row_2_data = row_2[data_position]
            if row_1_data != row_2_data:
                print "oh no, the data doesn't match!"

            # Heres how you'd right the rows 
                row_to_write = []

                #Differences between
                for row_1_column, row_2_column in itertools.izip(row_1_data, row_2_data):
                    row_to_write.append(row_1_column - row_2_column)

                writer.writerow(row_to_write)


    # Make sure to close those files! 
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    outputFile.close()

main()
```

Comment: In java the HashMaps work just as well as Dictionaries. For csv libraries I've heard OpenCsv and Appache's CommonCsv would both work for what you need.

Comment: If this is a project for school and you need to design the csv reader yourself. I'd suggest parsing the file line by line, and using String.split() on the csv's delimiter (usually a ',' ), storing the lines as an arrayList of strings is pretty much what any Csv reader is doing.